# Trying to install Django

Tags: django, pip, python-3.4

I have been trying to install Django correctly for a while to no avail.

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.7.2\Django-1.7.2\setup.py
```

raises an exception and stores the following in a log file:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip run on 01/12/15 17:47:02
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2606, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2544, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2512, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])

ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\Django-1.7.2\\Django-1.7.2\\setup.py', 'at', ':\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\Django-1.7.2\\Django-1.7.2\\setup.py')
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!
THANK YOU

Comment: You need to run either `pip install Django==1.7` or `python setup.py install`, not a combination of both.

Comment: That should be an answer not a comment, @SimeonVisser.

Comment: Not really because Windows pip issues aren't my area.

Answer (score 0):

For `pip install` refer to the directory containing `setup.py`.

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.7.2\Django-1.7.2\
```

But since your path has `site-packages` in it already (e.g. `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\`) it would seem that it is **already installed**.

Other alternatives are:

- `pip install django==1.7.2`
- `pip install django==1.7`
- `python C:...\Django-1.7.2\setup.py install`